eBay Digital Signatures header 215113 error Invalid timestamp in signature parameters
I am trying to create digital signature for Ebay API. I always get error 215113 "Invalid timestamp in signature parameters". I am using long timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds(); to get timestamp. Here is full code:
`
private static string privateKeyBase64 = "";
private static string jwePublicKey = "";
    public static async Task MakeSignedRequest()
    {
        long timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        string method = "GET";
        string authority = "apiz.sandbox.ebay.com";
        string path = "/sell/finances/v1/payout";
        string contentType = "application/json";
        string payload = "";

        string keyId = "";
       
        string jwePublicKey = "";
        Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters privateKey = LoadEd25519PrivateKey(privateKeyBase64);
        var coveredComponents = new List<string>
        {
            $"@method: {method}",
            $"@path: {path}",
            $"@authority: {authority}",
            $"@content-digest: sha-256={ComputeContentDigest(payload)}",
            $"content-type: {contentType}"
        };

        string signatureBase = CreateSignatureBase(coveredComponents, timestamp, keyId);
        string signature = SignData(signatureBase, privateKey);

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"https://{authority}{path}");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer token");
            request.Headers.Add("Signature-Input", $"sig1=({string.Join(" ", coveredComponents)});created={timestamp};keyid=\"{keyId}\"");
            request.Headers.Add("Signature", $"sig1=:{signature}:");
            request.Headers.Add("x-ebay-signature-key", jwePublicKey);
            request.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID", "EBAY_DE");

            // Content headers should be added to the HttpContent object
            var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, contentType);
            request.Content = content;

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            Console.WriteLine($"Response StatusCode: {response.StatusCode}");
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"Response Body: {responseBody}");
        }
    }

    public static string SignData(string dataToSign, Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters privateKey)
    {
        var signer = new Ed25519Signer();
        signer.Init(true, privateKey);
        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToSign);
        signer.BlockUpdate(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
        byte[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
    }


    public static Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters LoadEd25519PrivateKey(string privateKeyBase64)
    {
        byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyBase64);
        return (Ed25519PrivateKeyParameters)PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(keyBytes);
    }



    private static string CreateSignatureBase(List<string> coveredComponents, long created, string keyId)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var component in coveredComponents)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"{component}");
        }
        sb.AppendLine($"@signature-params: (created={created}; keyid='{keyId}'; {string.Join("; ", coveredComponents)})");
        return sb.ToString().TrimEnd();
    }

    private static string ComputeContentDigest(string payload)
    {
        using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
            return "sha-256=:" + Convert.ToBase64String(hash) + ":";
        }
    }
}

}
`
I tried to debug and solve that timestamp error, but I can't get it right.

The code formatting needs improvement. Please read this answer on syntax highlighting.
